# Vetting new IT development staff

Tags: audit, physical, data-leakage, source-code

In the realm of software development what would be the best way to vet prospective employees?

We handle potentially sensitive information, and a code base which could be potentially lucrative to competitors.

I understand that there is only so much that one could do, and unfortunately there is only so much information & access we could withhold from a developer without stifling their output.

Anybody with any experience or thoughts on vetting would be much appreciated - Baring in mind that we do not have any real budget set aside for this purpose.

Comment: If you're unwilling to spend the budget for a security check, it means either that you do not really need that security or you shouldn't be going on with your project because you do not have the necessary resources to carry it through. In neither case will an answer here assist you even if that question was in scope for this web site

Comment: We operate in the NFP sector, where budgets are low and data is valuable. Unfortunately there is not a lot that can be changed here. How would you suggest that this question, based around security & IT is out of scope for this stack exchange?

Comment: Leave a $100/€100/whatever note on the floor in a restroom/corridor/pantry/meeting room where the candidate will be alone. If it disappears: don't hire.

Comment: @KristoferA The worst thing is - that is probably the most cost/time effective way

Comment: @AaronDobbing I haven't used that one with devs, but we always do that when we hire a new housekeeper... Leave some cash around, see if it disappears. If not, she's considered trustworthy enough.